Ubuntu boot only in safe graphics (recovery) even after amdgpu-install
I got a new pc with:
CPU: ryzen 4600g CPU
Motherboard: Gigabyte B450M DS3H V2 bios at latest version
no external GPU
I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4
kernel version 6.5.0-45-generic
it doesn't boot except in recovery or with nomodeset in /etc/default/grub
I got latest amdgpu driver from https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/6.1.3/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_6.1.60103-1_all.deb
then ran sudo amdgpu-install
followed the steps of the documentation then rebooted but the issue wasn't solved

did you follow this instruction: https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-prereq.html#installing-the-installer-package

@amar yes I followed that
